# Convert to predicate logic: the relation $R$ on the set $X$ is antisymmetric

Tags: predicate-logic

How would I cast the following to logical symbols

> The relation $R$ on the set $X$ is antisymmetric.

Answer (score 0):

$(\forall a \in X)(\forall b \in X)\left [(aRb  \wedge a\not = b) \implies \lnot bRa \right]$